# Android Webview gives suggesstions for Password textbox

Tags: android, textbox, passwords, android-webview

In Android webview simple html file with password input textbox loaded. While typing in that textbox, suggestions are displayed. That's typing D in textbox suggestions like (demo, etc) showed but the textbox having dot's like characters. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is problem with device settings ,So try the below steps might be useful

Go to the settings app and scroll down to language and input. In the line for device keyboard at the far right there is an icon for settings. If you tap the icon features for the devicekeyboard will come up. One of those features will be for predictive typing. You can either slide the switch to the off position or tap the row for customization.